# router.navigateByUrl() causes navigation to root and reload, angular 2.4.7

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

### navigateByUrl causes navigation to root and reload

When I use router.navigate() or navigateByUrl(), I get a reload - a 
call to the root. The Chrome Dev tools console shows

`Navigated to http://localhost/`

Navigation via links with 
`<a [routerLink]=`
works correctly.

## app

- was generated using angular-cli. Components were generated then modified.
- has 3 components test1, test11 (a child of test1) and test2
- navigating between test11 and test2 works fine via anchor tag links with 
  [routerLink] (declarative)
- navigating from test2 to test11 by using (click) event 
  and programmatic (imperative) navigation call 

  `this.router.navigateByUrl('/test1/test11');`

## environment

`angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
   node: 7.5.0
   os: win32 x64
   @angular/common: 2.4.7
   @angular/compiler: 2.4.7
   @angular/core: 2.4.7
   @angular/forms: 2.4.7
   @angular/http: 2.4.7
   @angular/platform-browser: 2.4.7
   @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.7
   @angular/router: 3.4.7
   @angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.7`

## code

Is published to GitHub, [published to GitHub](https://github.com/michaelkariv/angular_router_demo)

`https://github.com/michaelkariv/angular_router_demo`

## served by ng serve using production environment

`serve --host localhost --port 80 --live-reload false  -prod`

## What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For all the viewers, here is the update. By now angular has moved on to version 4. So may be (I did not check) the problem went away. I don't know. I had shelved the project. Now I am reopening it. And I have decided to move away from angular 2 and up + bootstrap and to ionic 2  framework. Ionic framework mimics mobile navigation and wraps the router in its own implementation. That implementation is easier to deal with. I was trying to make a web version of a mobile app anyway - so ionic is the most natural way to go. So my needs this problem is now moot.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, when anchor clicked it will trigger browser's default navigation

```
<a href="" (click)="goToTest11()"> router.navigateByUrl('../test1/test11')</a>
```

to fix that use event.preventDefault()

```
<a href="" (click)="$event.preventDefault();goToTest11();"> router.navigateByUrl('../test1/test11')</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your code so this is just a guess, but I think you have missed router-outlet in your app.component.html

```html
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Add the above code to your app.component.html file in the end

Comment: Sorry I'll check later and let you know, but for the time being I got so tired with the router that I moved to ionic framework - and away from the vanilla angular2 + bootstrap. Ionic framework mimics mobile navigation and wraps the router in its own implementation. That implementation is easier to deal with. I was trying to make a web version of a mobile app anyway - so ionic is the most natural way to go.